# zip functionality in python behaving weird

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-itertools, python-zip

```
>>> l1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> l2 = ['G', 'F', 'K', 'J']
>>> for (i, j) in zip(l1, l2):
      print(i, j)
      l1.pop(0)
      print(l1)
      print(l2)
```

output is :
'A'
A G
['B', 'C']
['G', 'F', 'K', 'J']
'B'
C F
['C']
['G', 'F', 'K', 'J']

Expected :
'A'
A G      # line 2
['B', 'C']
['G', 'F', 'K', 'J']
'B'
C F        # line 3
['C']
['G', 'F', 'K', 'J']

l2 still has ['C']. Why ? Also, at line 2 how come A is there, when A is already popped.
If it means, that i took the value already before popping, then why line 3 has C F. It should be B F.

Please explain. I am totally confused here.

Comment: Try  `zip(l1[:], l2[:])`.  Are those the results you actually expected?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem because you are popping A after the zip function is executed. So even if you remove all elements in `l1` and `l2` in the first iteration, the loop executes the same because the `zip()` function had already returned the values before first iteration. `range()`, `zip()` or whatever function you provide on the for in , it will execute first, then it will iterate, modifying the original values won't change anything, because it is already returned as a separate value.